# Alert keeps staying even after reload

Tags: javascript, express, ejs

Express:

```
router.get('/polls/new', isLoggedIn, (req, res) => {
    res.render('new', {title: 'Create a new poll', route: 'new', isLoggedIn: req.isAuthenticated(), errors: req.session.errors});
    req.session.errors = null;
});

router.post('/polls', isLoggedIn, (req, res) => {
    req.check('title', 'Title must contain atleast 10 characters and must not exceed 100 charcters').isLength({min: 10, max: 100});
    var errors = req.validationErrors();
    console.log(errors);
    if (errors) {
        req.session.errors = errors;
        res.redirect('/polls/new');
    }
```

EJS:

```
<% if (errors)  { %>
<% errors.forEach((error) => { %>
    <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
      <button type="button" class="close alert-dismissible" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
      <strong>Error!</strong> <%= error.msg %>
    </div>
<% }); } %>
```

Am trying to show alert messages when the validation fails. It works perfectly fine. But when the page is reloaded the alert message still shows up even if I made the errors null.

Comment: Try putting `<% console.log(errors) %>` in your EJS file. I doubt it'll log anything surprising but it should help to confirm that the template actually does run. I'm wondering whether you're seeing some sort of caching problem. You could also put something like `<%= Date.now() %>` in your EJS to help confirm that you aren't seeing a cached copy in your browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The call to `res.render` effectively ends your HTTP request, so anything that happens to `req` or `res` after render has been called will effectively have never happened. Try duplicating the value of `errors` in another variable like:

```
router.get('/polls/new', isLoggedIn, (req, res) => {
    let err = req.session.errors;
    req.session.errors = null;
    res.render('new', {title: 'Create a new poll', route: 'new', isLoggedIn: 
        req.isAuthenticated(), errors: err});
});
```